# mail app not sending appropriate Reply To addresses from different email accounts

Tags: mail.app, gmail, smtp

My wife has a MacBook Pro (10.8.2) with a Telus home internet connection. She uses the Mac mail app (6.2) and her primary email account is a Gmail address, which she has been using with no problem (using Gmail's imap and smtp servers).

She recently asked me to set up another Gmail account, which I did, but whenever she sends a new email, the Reply To address is for her original account. In an effort to trouble shoot the problem, I activated her Telus email account, which she does not normally use.

Here's the setup:

1. Gmail account (primary account)      -  imap.gmail.com,    smtp.gmail.com (with password authentication)
2. Gmail account (new account)           - imap.gmail.com,    smtp.gmail.com (with password authentication)
3. Telus account                         - imap.telus.net,    smtp.telus.net (with no authentication, as suggested by Telus)

She can send and receive from all three accounts, but the Reply To address is always account no. 1.

She selects the correct account in the drop-down From menu when composing her email

Each account has its own smtp setup, with the correct name and password in the authentication, in the case of the Gmail accounts.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. I had forgotten that a long time ago I had set 'Reply To' for all email accounts, using a command line in the Terminal.

I reset the defults, by using 'defaults delete com.apple.mail UserHeaders'

All three accounts now work as expected.